# Encontrar el máximo valor de un grupo de valores en mi tabla Mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, datatables, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

alguien me pudiera ayudar a resolver lo siguiente:

mi tabla es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que yo deseo que me muestre es: los registros que tengan mayor valor dentro de la columna **state**  y tengan la misma serie y numero por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resto de columnas se deberían también mostrar en la consulta

intente con esta query

```
SELECT  serie, number, document_type, max(state), issue_date, approval_date
FROM documents 
where emitter_company_id=26
group by  concat(serie,number)
```

pero no es lo que espero por que el resto de columnas que muestra sigue siendo del menor valor (-1)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué consulta has intentado? Puedes resolverlo con un GROUP BY y la función MAX.

Comment: editare mi pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No haría falta un GROUP BY, tan solo comparar el state con el valor máximo obtenido en una subconsulta:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    documents d
WHERE
    d.state = (SELECT MAX(d2.state) FROM documents d2 WHERE d.serie = d2.serie AND d.number = d2.number )
    AND d.emitter_company_id = 26;
```

Comment: esta query me retorna la tabla completa no filtra al maximo valor por que basicamente serie,number, document_type, issue_date, approval_date no son iguales simpre, lo que necesito es filtrar cuando serie y number sean iguales

Comment: Y agrupando por serie y number solo no te vale porque necesitas todos los campos?

Comment: asi es, necesito el resto de columnas también  e incluso he probado esto: SELECT  *
FROM documents 
where state in (select max(state)as estado from documents group by  concat(serie,number))
group by  concat(serie,number)
having emitter_company_id = 26

Comment: Modifico la respuesta.